# Trigger not working properly with GetComponent. What is wrong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the player health script... It set's the players health from within Unity, and pushes it onto the GUI.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{


    public Text hpText; //HP Value Text Element.
    public int PlayerHP; // Make it a property so you can alter its value in the editor

    void Start()
    {
        SetHPText ();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        SetHPText ();
    }

    void SetHPText ()
    {
        hpText.text = "Health: " + PlayerHP.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then this one takes the grabs the players current health (and keeps it updated). If the players health is 0 (or lower) it loads a new scene. The problem is the tag tag check for the player, and apply damage aren't working.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class DamageAuroa : MonoBehaviour {

    public int PHP; //PHP = Player Health from PlayerHealth.cs script.
    public int Damage; //Amount of damage.
    public string Level;

    void Update()
    {
        PHP = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent&lt;PlayerHealth&gt;().PlayerHP;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            PHP = PHP - Damage;

        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ball")
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(Level);
        }

        if (PHP &lt;= 0)
            SceneManager.LoadScene(Level);

    }

}
```

The weirdest part ALL OF THIS was working prior to me updating Unity (I know newbie mistake). Anyone see what's the matter? Before anyone asks yes the triggers, and tags are set up properly. Also I realize I have to pass the updated HP value to the player health script for it to update on the GUI. Just trying to get these triggers working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code doesn't work because you are creating new variable `PHP` that equals to player HP (but doesn't reference to it, because `int` is a value type, not a reference type) and when you change `PHP` it changes only this variable, not `PlayerHP` from `PlayerHealth` script.

```
    void Update()
    {
        PHP = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().PlayerHP;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            PHP = PHP - Damage;

        ....

    }
```

If you want to change `PlayerHealth` you should change it directly from `PlayerHealth` script instance.

```
if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Player")
                GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().PlayerHP= PHP - Damage;
```

Or you can create an reference type variable references to `PlayerHealth` script.

```
public class DamageAuroa : MonoBehaviour {

     PlayerHealth player;

     void Start () 
     {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
     } 
   ...
```

And then use this object to set players hp.

```
if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Player")
   player.PlayerHP = player.PlayerHP- Damage;
```

Comment: I tried that, and it doesn't change the Player Health at all. It just stays the same. Also I've double checked all my tags, and triggers they're fine.

Comment: @user1768885 Did you set Damage? Have you tried to set HP to different values in this script?

Comment: I did. Still nothing. Also I'm aware I need to pass the updated value back to player hp value somehow so it updates the GUI.

Comment: @user1768885 In order to change hpText you should change PlayerHP in PlayerHealth, you can do it this way - GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().PlayerHP= PHP - Damage;

Comment: @user1768885 Can you show a trigger object? Does it have Mesh Collider?

Comment: This is so frustrating. Alright so I tried that instead which should work. It finds the Player, gets PlayerHP, and updates it with the new amount (Damage). I checked both scripts, and the health value remains the same no matter what.

Comment: Oh I'm a moron. I... forgot to add a box collider, and trigger. Thank you so much.

Comment: I also wanted to implement damage over time. So I made a OnTriggerStay method. If I wanted to use Time.deltaTime to do so how would I do that? Basically I want to do that damage amount every second, but I don't know how to put it in the GetComponent statement.

Comment: @user1768885 Probably you need to create bool variable like IsInside and in Update method make if statement if (IsInside) { ... damage logic here ... }. But it is another question

Answer (score 0):

Aye well I am not sure if this will work because i am not as advanced my self, but try using coll.tag, because the collier class has a tag variable it self.